# How do I run a project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Working on a project in Eclipse 3.6, I used the subeclipse subversion stuff to download my file and now whenever I try to run it I get the following error:

> The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches

Any ideas guys?

Comment: What is what you downloaded? a full project? a dynamic web project? a single .java file?

Comment: Downloaded a java web project (trying to learn how to use spring, struts, and hibernate . . . nightmare).

Comment: I am only familiar with using Eclipse IDE for Java GUI-based projects. I have no experience yet for web-based Java projects. But, I think the tool still behaves the same in term of usage irrespective of any project type. I am not so clear the issue with SVN in your case as I have a project with SVN enabled in Eclipse IDE using Subeclipse plugin and I see no issue whatsoever.

Comment: My suggestion is to create a blank web-based Java project in your given workspace folder. Then pull your SVN branch into this newly-created project folder under the workspace folder. Fire up your Eclipse, right-click on the new project in the Project Explorer and choose Refresh menu option to streamline Eclipse with the actual contents of the project folder. After that, clean up your project Build Path properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a downloaded project,
first you have to import it:

1. Go to project explorer
2. Right click
3. Select import
4. If it is a war file choose as it or import as **file system**. There are many choices there. After that you have to add *REQUIRED JAR* on its **class path**, or if its a *web project* you have to add *REQUIRED JAR* in `WEB_INF/lib folder`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends a bit on what kind of project this is..... Eclipse supports different kinds of launchers for different kinds of projects.

But assuming it's a relatively standard Java project, just right click on the main class and do "Run As... / Java Application".

This should launch your application, and Eclipse will remember this configuration the next time you try to run.

Comment: It is not locating my java web file (trying to use spring, struts, and hibernate) when I do OPEN AS ... JAVA APPLICATION.  As it is now, the only way I can access the individual files and edit them is by clicking OPEN FILE from the File menu and specifically locating the files in my eclipse/../workspace folder.  Any ideas on how to get it to locate my file?

Comment: Hello . . . is anyone there?  Did I do something wrong?  Help. . pls?